# Theories to suggest that there exists only one version of history

Tags: metaphysics, time

How do we know that the past is fixed and that there only exists one version of history?

Are there any interesting arguments surrounding this?

Comment: We do not, and one version is used for simplicity (Occam's razor). Unless one believes in determinism, in which case there is also a single future. The laws of physics are time symmetric, and quantum mechanics is just as consistent with multiple futures as it is with multiple pasts, see [Wikipedia's Multiple Histories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_histories).

Comment: Of course there's only one version of history: the *whole* complicated, complex truth. I like to call it reality. If we were omniscient we would know *all* of it. But (perhaps fortunately) we can do no better than to settle for attempting to understand the most important, critical parts of it, and the aspects of which we have some first or second-hand knowledge.